# Python OpenCV template matching and feature detection not working properly

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I'm attempting to identify specific shapes in an image using a template. I've edited the original image by adding two stars to it. Now, I'm trying to detect the positions of these stars, but it doesn't seem to be recognizing them. I've employed two methods, template matching and feature detection, but neither is yielding the expected results.

My primary objective is to successfully detect both stars and connect them to form a rectangular shape, ultimately providing me with just the answers area as a result in a new image. However, my initial focus is on accurately detecting the marks.

The base image and the template are as follows:

[image][image]

First i've tried to match the image with the template.

```
# Load the base image and the black star image
base_image = cv2.imread(path_saida_jpg, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
star_template = cv2.imread(path_base_star, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

base_gray = cv2.cvtColor(base_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
star_template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(star_template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Perform template matching to find the stars
result = cv2.matchTemplate(base_image, star_template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.80  
locations = np.where(result >= threshold)

# Draw rectangles around the found stars
for loc in zip(*locations[::-1]):
    h, w = star_template.shape[:2]
    cv2.rectangle(base_image, loc, (loc[0] + w, loc[1] + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)  # Draw a green rectangle

    cv2.imwrite('result_image.jpg', base_image)
```

The locations were always empty, the software as only capable to find some match when i down the threshold variable to 0.6. but the result wasn't the expected.  Here it is:

[image]

Afterward, I realized that the issue might be related to scale. Consequently, I attempted to address it using feature detection and matching with ORB (Oriented FAST and Rotated BRIEF). In my initial attempt, I obtained no results when using the template image at its original scale, which was 64px. Consequently, I decided to increase its size to 512px, hoping to enhance the chances of success. Surprisingly, the outcome was even less favorable. Below is the code and the resulting output:

```
base_image = cv2.imread(path_saida_jpg, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
star_template = cv2.imread(path_base_star, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

base_gray = cv2.cvtColor(base_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
star_template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(star_template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(base_gray, None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(star_template_gray, None)
 
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

matches = bf.match(des1, des2)

matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)

result_image = cv2.drawMatches(base_image, kp1, star_template, kp2, matches[:10], None, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

# Export the result
cv2.imwrite('result_image.jpg', result_image)
```

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm relatively new to the field of image processing, and I find myself somewhat disoriented in the midst of this complex task. I've been using ChatGPT and resources from GeeksforGeeks to assist me.

Comment: Make sure your template is the exact same size as the symbols in the image. Then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74232586/opencv-multiple-template-matching-improving-matching/74256333#74256333 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779288/how-to-template-match-a-simple-2d-shape-in-opencv/61780200#61780200 for examples of matching multiple objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have cropped your star from your image to use as a template in Python/OpenCV template matching. I then use a technique of masking the correlation image in a loop to find the two matches. Each top match is masked out with zeros in the TM_CCORR_NORMED (normalized cross correlation) surface before searching for the next top match.

- Read the input
- Read the template
- Set arguments
- Compute TM_CCORR_NORMED image
- Loop over matches, if max_val > match_threshold, save correlation location and value and mask the correlation image. Then repeat until max_val below match_thresh.
- Save results

Input:

[image]

Template:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('prova_da_epcar.jpg')

# read template
tmplt = cv2.imread('star.png')
hh, ww, cc = tmplt.shape

# set arguments
match_thresh = 0.95               # stopping threshold for match value
num_matches = 10                  # stopping threshold for number of matches
match_radius = max(hh,ww)//4      # approx radius of match peaks

# get correlation surface from template matching
corrimg = cv2.matchTemplate(img,tmplt,cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
hc, wc = corrimg.shape

# get locations of all peaks higher than match_thresh for up to num_matches
imgcopy = img.copy()
corrcopy = corrimg.copy()
for i in range(1, num_matches):
    # get max value and location of max
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(corrcopy)
    x1 = max_loc[0]
    y1 = max_loc[1]
    x2 = x1 + ww
    y2 = y1 + hh
    loc = str(x1) + "," + str(y1)
    if max_val > match_thresh:
        print("match number:", i, "match value:", max_val, "match x,y:", loc)
        # draw draw blue bounding box to define match location
        cv2.rectangle(imgcopy, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,0,255), 2)
        # draw black filled circle over copy of corrimg 
        cv2.circle(corrcopy, (x1,y1), match_radius, 0, -1)
        # faster alternate - insert black rectangle
        # corrcopy[y1:y2, x1:x2] = 0
        i = i + 1
    else:
        break
    
# save results
# power of 4 exaggeration of correlation image to emphasize peaks
cv2.imwrite('prova_da_epcar_corr.png', (255*cv2.pow(corrimg,4)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('prova_da_epcar_star_corr_masked.png', (255*cv2.pow(corrcopy,4)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('prova_da_epcar_star_multi_match.png', imgcopy)


# show results
# power of 4 exaggeration of correlation image to emphasize peaks
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('template', tmplt)
cv2.imshow('corr', cv2.pow(corrimg,4))
cv2.imshow('corr masked', cv2.pow(corrcopy,4))
cv2.imshow('result', imgcopy)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Correlation Image:

[image]

Final Masked Correlation Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

I suggest in the future that you use 3 or 4 symbols in your image to help if your image is slightly rotated. You might also consider using a ring as your symbol to be rotation independent.

I also suggest that you use cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED (or cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED and mask with white) rather than cv2.TM_CCOEF_NORMED

There are also [non-maxima suppression](https://pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/) methods for detecting multiple matches that do not need masking. See this [example](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/29/multi-template-matching-with-opencv/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, however the code didn't work here. Maybe there is something missing in the installation? I literally copied your code inside vscode and replace the templates. To guarantee i've downloaded the images that you provided in the question and nothing!  
The Correlation Image and the masked correlation image are in a complete gray, without the areas that are in the images. Any ideia of what it could be?
I'm using 
numpy==1.25.2
opencv-contrib-python==4.8.0.76
opencv-python==4.8.0.76

Comment: And thank you for the rotation advice, the software will need to find the stars in scanned images so it's very important. I will adopt the strategy to use circle markers, maybe targets and place 4 of them around the Area. I forgot to say that the base image is just an example of reply card. I'm using the markers because it can have any layout, just the markers should be equal.

Comment: Now it works, i've downloaded your template too to use in the image. The white background in the image is extremely necessary? My png does not have a background, probably that is my problem. I will try to change the png, add a background to it and place four target markers in my main image and try again. Maybe i'll return here haha.

Comment: @Max Yes, the white background in the template is necessary. Cross correlation works by looking for a piece of information (the template) in a larger signal (the document). To get a reasonable match score, the template must closely resemble the picture found within the document. Your original image might have an alpha (transparency) channel, which gets ignored by the default reading mode in imread. It might be turning those pixels black instead of white.

Comment: If your image is transparent, make sure to remove the alpha channel. If your template is transparent, in the code extract the bgr image without transparency and alpha channel. Then use the extracted alpha channel as a mask image with the bgr image in matchTemplate. It permits a mask so that the template background will not contribute. Search Google or this forum for examples. If both images are plain black on white, then the code should work, provided there is no relative scale or rotation between the template and the image.

Comment: For template matching with transparent template, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302061/how-do-i-find-an-image-on-screen-ignoring-transparent-pixels/71302306#71302306